# Android get URL to InputStream

Tags: android, xml, parsing, download, httpurlconnection

My mission is to parse some XML from a website from Android. Everything works fine if I paste the XML to a String and then convert it to a InputStream and parse it. But if I try to download the XML using `HttpURLConnection` it only downloads the "half" and skips the root element and some attributes in the beginning and at the end.

The thing I want to parse looks like this:

```
<Page xmlns:i... xmlns="...">
<Body>...</Body>
<Contact i:nil=".."/>
<ID>...</ID>
<Date>...</Date>
<Summary>..</Summary>
<Title>...</Title>
</Page>
```

The thing I get when I download and print out:

```
<ID>...</ID>
<Date>...</Date>
<Summary>..</Summary>
<Title>...</Title
```

and hence the parse fails as it does not get what it expected. My code for downloading:

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
conn.setConnectTimeout(25000 /* milliseconds */);
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setUseCaches(true);
conn.connect();
InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
return stream;
```

Why does it not download the whole XML page from the net when it really is reachable?

Answer (score 0):

The problem got fixed if I added the following line:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", " application/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

Good to know.